# pushViewController Not Pushing A New View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have two view controllers and a button in my storyboard. I don't understand why this is not pushing the view to the second view controller. I have the Storyboard ID and Class of FirstViewController, so shouldn't it work? I keep getting this error Unknown class FirstViewController in Interface Builder file. What am I doing wrong?

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller in your storyboard, connected with FirstViewControlled as a rootViewController?

Comment: No I didn't. Thank you, I tried it and it worked. However, I didn't really want a navigation controller in the app. Is there another way to do this without having a navigation controller?

Comment: self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Cheers, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just to have an answer for others -->

Two ways to solve it ->

1.Add a navigationController in the storyboard, as you cannot do pushViewController on a viewController outside navigationController's stack.

2.You can push it as a modal view controller, using `self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` 
This will give a modal effect, and not the normal push effect.